# "По" или "для" в конкретном случае?

Tags: психология

Как правильно: "программное обеспечение по психологическому диагностированию" или "программное обеспечение для психологического диагностирования"?

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, правильно *для. Обеспечение **по*** как-то непонятно звучит, а *ПО для диагностирования* (для какой цели?) — отлично.